# Is there a Base58 encoder function that runs in pure javascript without node?

Tags: javascript, base58

I see a lot of JavaScript Base58 encoder functions online, but all of them seem to require node.  Is there a simple JavaScript Base58 encoder that will just run in the browser without any node installation or modification?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure javascript base58 encoder fuction I helped put together. Included are some comments that helped me understand what is going on beyond the barebones functions you can find elsewhere.

```
function encode_b58(hex_number) {
    // Set of base58 chars (Note: there is no '0','O','I' or 'l').
    const base58 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
    //Take input string of hexadecimal bytes and convert it to a base 10
    //decimal number. BigInt needed as regular JS numbers don't represent enough significant digits.
    var num = BigInt('0x' + hex_number);
    //Our very large number will be repeatedly divided by 58.
    const fifty8 = BigInt(58);
    //The remainder of this division will be a number (0-57).
    var remainder;
    //Each remainder's value maps to a character in our base58 array, and
    //the string of these characters becomes our Base58 encoded output.
    var b58_encoded_buffer = '';
    //We move from: Hex Bytes -> Decimal Number -> Base58 Encoded string.
    //To move through each place value of a base58 number, we continue to
    //divide by 58, until the integer number rounds down to 0.
    while (num > 0) {
        //The modulus operator returns our remainder, which depends on
        //the least significant digit in our BigInt converted input.
        //For example: if we were doing modulo 2 division, all odd
        //numbers - regardless of how long they are - would return a
        //remainder of 1, because the least significant digit is odd.
        remainder = num % fifty8;

        //Thus, we're encoding the right most (lowest place value)
        //digits first, and so each subsequently encoded character
        //needs to be added to the left of our encoded buffer
        //so that the beginning & end of our input string/bytes aligns
        //with the beginning & end of our Base58 encoded output.
        b58_encoded_buffer = base58[remainder] + b58_encoded_buffer;

        //Dividing by 58 gives us our quotient (rounded down to the
        //nearest integer), and moves us over one base58 place value,
        //ready for the next round of b58 division/mapping/encoding.
        num = num/BigInt(58);
    }

    //When we convert our byte-based hex input into a base 10 number, we
    //lose the leading zero bytes in the converted decimal number.
    //For example, if our hex input converted into the decimal number
    //000017, this number would be reduced automatically to 17 in base10,
    //and so we'd lose the leading zeros, which aren't important
    //when doing base 10 math, but are important in preserving the
    //information held in our original input value. So, in order to not
    //lose the leading zeros, we count them, and then prepend them (as
    //1's, which is their corresponding base58 value) to the beginning
    //of our Base58 encoded output string.
    while ( hex_number.match(/^00/) ){
        //For each leading zero byte, add a '1' to the encoded output.
        b58_encoded_buffer = '1' + b58_encoded_buffer;
        //And remove the leading zero byte, and test for another.
        hex_number = hex_number.substring(2);
    }

    return b58_encoded_buffer;
}
```